# Could not find endpoint element with name WCF

Tags: c#

I send name to endpoint but I get error.

**Error:**

Could not find endpoint element with name 'HTTP_Port' and contract 'WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

[image]

**WebConfig:**

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="https://example.company.eu:51201"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InvoiceCheck_OutBinding"
                contract="WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out" name="HTTP_Port" />
            <endpoint address="https://example.company.eu:51201"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InvoiceCheck_OutBinding1"
                contract="WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out" name="HTTPS_Port" />
</client>
```

I put this here work correct **App.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SharePoint" publicKeyToken="71E9BCE111E9429C" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="InvoiceCheck_OutBinding" />
          <binding name="InvoiceCheck_OutBinding1">
            <security mode="Transport" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="http://test"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InvoiceCheck_OutBinding"
            contract="WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out" name="HTTP_Port" />
        <endpoint address="https://test"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InvoiceCheck_OutBinding1"
            contract="WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out" name="HTTPS_Port" />
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How is your code being run? If it is in say a console application I see no problem. If your code is being loaded in at runtime from another library (i.e. plugin) then that might be your problem with locating the config file

Comment: I use this as .dll for test. Later I call this from console application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are referencing this code as a dll your code is going to be checking your application (in your case your console app) that is referencing it for the configuration. Try taking your `<System.ServiceModel>` configuration from your dll and adding it to the app.config for your console application that should work.

Comment: I didn't understood  the answer. Please @RafałDeveloper can you explain in details. Thanks!